# Making ToC page numbers flushleft, and not flush right

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, page-numbering

My ToC has all page numbers appear just next to the entry heading. This works fine when the page numbers are small; however, with four small roman numerals the page number meets the entry heading. It seems to me the page numbers are flush right, and "moving leftwards". I would like them to move rightwards from the place where the first digit is placed, i.e. flush left. Further, the flush-right-nature of the page numbers make the space between entry heading and page number vary, which I do not like.

The problem arises due to all the preliminary pages of my thesis. Please see MWE which shows the problem. Is there a way to fix this?

Sincerely,
Anders

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{memoir}


% page number next to TOC entries

\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftfigureleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cfttableleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttableafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter

    \chapter*{Abstract} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
        This study...

    \chapter*{Samandrag} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samandrag}
        Dette forsøket...

    \chapter*{Preface} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
        Information about the nature of the study.

    \chapter*{Acknowledgements} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
        I wish to thank...

    \cleardoublepage

    \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage

    \listoffigures
        \cleardoublepage

    \listoftables
        \cleardoublepage


\mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}



\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `\chapter*` + `\addcontentsline` within frontmatter, there `\chapter` is formatted the same way.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I did it to work around a "bug" from my thesis code. Without the starred chapter, the ToC entries of "Abstract" and "Samandrag" would be centered on the page, while none of the other chapters would be.

Comment: Well it does not on the MWE

Comment: I guess the MWE could be even more minimal, then. I have a messy self-made package with all the formatting. Probably something in there causes the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{%
  \cftchapterformatpnumhook{#1}%
  %\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\cftchapterpagefont #1}
  {\quad\cftchapterpagefont #1}
}
```

Also see my comment on `\chapter*`

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!